# ASP.NET Claim NameIdentifier Id gets convert error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

i have problem with this code:

```
private async Task<object> GenerateJwtToken(string email, User user)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id)
    };
```

User extend IdentityUser. The problem is that i get :

> Cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity'".
>   Even for ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier i get error: "Cannot convert from
>   'string' to 'System.IO.BinaryReader'

And if i change Id to something else, like email, or firstName errors disappear... Can't find any info about it.

Comment: Seems a VS Code bug, I just erased the parameters and typed them again and just worked!

Answer (score 8):

I have this error on Visual Code at new `Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.Username)`, telling `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.BinaryReader'`. My code was like this:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReadUser([FromBody]UserDto userDto){

        User userFromRepo = _authRepository.GetUserAsync();
        //generate token for user
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("my secret key");
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor{
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userFromRepo.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.Username) //error here in this ctor

            }),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
        };
```

After adding `await` keyword missing before my repository method, which is async by the way, the error is now gone.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReadUser([FromBody]UserDto userDto){

        User userFromRepo = await _authRepository.GetUserAsync(); //added await
        //generate token for user
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("my secret key");
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor{
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userFromRepo.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.Username) //error gets fixed

            }),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
        };
```

Maybe you were facing something similar to this?

Answer (score 7):

Understandably I am a bit late to this question but I had a similar issue.

What I found was new Claim has multiple signatures that can be passed into it. Explicitly stating the type resolved my issue.

```cs
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name as string, userFromRepo.Username as string)
```

Hopefully this gives some help to anyone else who has this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Normally how it works (at least in ASP.NET Core 3) is that the `sub` JWT claim gets automatically converted (by the `InboundClaimTypeMap`) into `NameIdentifier` when the scaffolding instantiates the `ClaimsPrincipal`.

So it's enough to simply set a `JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub` claim with user.Id as value.

But you can customize which claim the Identity should use for identification purposes by assigning a value to `IdentityOptions.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType` in the `AddIdentity()` call, e.g.:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
   options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub;
});
```

And if you want to disable the claim mapping, you can clear the map by including the following statement in the configuration:

```cs
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

or set this flag to false:

```cs
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had a build error on my method signature. After fixing it the error fixed

My method signature is like this:

```
private async Task<User> AuthenticateUserAsync(string email, string password)
```

After defining "User" class build error related to method signature is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `user.Id` to a string

```
private async Task<object> GenerateJwtToken(string email, User user)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString())
    };
```